# how to synchronize a set of multiple threads with respect to a single thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

Suppose that I have an arraylist called myList of threads all of which are created with an instance of the class myRunnable implementing the Runnable interface, that is, all the threads share the same code to execute in the run() method of myRunnable. Now suppose that I have another single thread called singleThread that is created with an instance of the class otherRunnable implementing the Runnable interface.

The synchornization challenge I have to resolve for these threads is the following: I need all of the threads in myList to execute their code until certain point. Once reached this point, they shoud sleep. Once all and only all of the threads in myList are sleeping, then singleThread should be awakened (singleThread was already asleep). Then singleThread execute its own stuff, and when it is done, it should sleep and all the threads in myList should be awakened. Imagine that the codes are wrapped in while(true)'s, so this process must happen again and again.

Here is an example of the situation I've just described including an attempt of solving the synchronization problem:

```
class myRunnable extends Runnable
{
  public static final Object lock = new Object();
  static int count = 0;

  @override
  run()
  { 
     while(true)
     {
        //do stuff
        barrier();
        //do stuff
     }
  }

  void barrier()
  {
     try {
       synchronized(lock) {
          count++;
          if (count == Program.myList.size()) {
             count = 0;
             synchronized(otherRunnable.lock) {           
                otherRunnable.lock.notify();
             }
          }
          lock.wait();
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
  }
}

class otherRunnable extend Runnable
{
   public static final Object lock = new Object();

   @override
   run()
   {
     while(true)
     {
       try {
         synchronized(lock) {
            lock.wait();
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

       // do stuff

       try {
         synchronized(myRunnable.lock) {
           myRunnable.notifyAll();
       }
     }
   }        
}

class Program
{
  public static ArrayList<Thread> myList;

  public static void main (string[] args)
  {
     myList = new ArrayList<Thread>();

     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        myList.add(new Thread(new myRunnable()));
        myList.get(i).start();
     }
     new Thread(new OtherRunnable()).start();
  }
}
```

Basically my idea is to use a counter to make sure that threads in myList just wait except the last thread incrementing the counter, which resets the counter to 0, wakes up singleThread by notifying to its lock, and then this last thread goes to sleep as well by waiting to myRunnable.lock. In a more abstract level, my approach is to use some sort of barrier for threads in myList to stop their execution in a critical point, then the last thread hitting the barrier wakes up singleThread and goes to sleep as well, then singleThread makes its stuff and when finished, it wakes up all the threads in the barrier so they can continue again.

My problem is that there is a flaw in my logic (probably there are more).  When the last thread hitting the barrier notifies otherRunnable.lock, there is a chance that an immediate context switch could occur, giving the cpu to singleThread, before the last thread could execute its wait on myRunnable.lock (and going to sleep). Then singleThread would execute all its stuff, would execute notifyAll on myRunnable.lock, and all the threads in myList would be awakened except the last thread hitting the barrier because it has not yet executed its wait command. Then, all those threads would do their stuff again and would hit the barrier again, but the count would never be equal to myList.size() because the last thread mentioned earlier would be eventually scheduled again and would execute wait. singleThread in turn would also execute wait in its first line, and as a result we have a deadlock, with everybody sleeping.

So my question is: what would be a good way to synchronize these threads in order to achieve the desired behaviour described before but at the same time in a way safe of deadlocks??

Comment: tl;dr Can you give a higher-level description of the problem you're trying to solve? - there is probably a good solution in `java.util.concurrent` already.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear yet, so I will try to explain it again in simpler way. I have n threads and another thread x. I want to know a way to achieve the following behaviour: first n threads execute until a critical code line, then they stop their execution and go to sleep, then x is awakened and start execution, then x wakes up the n threads and go to sleep, then the n threads execute again until critical code line, stop execution, go to sleep, x is awakened again, and so on. In symbols: n -> x -> n -> x ....

Comment: One approach you may take is to have `OtherRunnable` check the states of all the other threads before calling notify all. If `OtherRunnable` sees any threads of `MyRunnable` are not in the waiting state, sleep and check again until all your `MyRunnable` threads are in the waiting state. See [Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html). (I didn't post this as an answer because it seems rather hacky to  me, but I suppose it should get the job done.)

Comment: Another way is to use a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). It sounds like it fits your need perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, sounds like a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) would fit your need exactly. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> A synchronization aid that **allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point**. CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because **it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released**.

Unfortunately, I haven't used them myself, so I can't give you specific pointers on them. I think the basic idea is you construct your barrier using the two-argument constructor with the `barrierAction`. Have your `n` threads `await()` on this barrier after this task is done, after which `barrierAction` is executed, after which the `n` threads will continue.

From the javadoc for `CyclicBarrier#await()`:

> If the current thread is the last thread to arrive, and a non-null barrier action was supplied in the constructor, then the current thread runs the action before allowing the other threads to continue. If an exception occurs during the barrier action then that exception will be propagated in the current thread and the barrier is placed in the broken state.